# Не могу забирать запросы Aiohttp из цикла - ошибка ValueError: I/O operation on closed file + aiohttp.payload.LookupError

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, aiohttp

Когда пробую перебрать список с API ключами в цикле, то вылазит две ошибки: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file AND aiohttp.payload.LookupError...

Вот функция запроса к API:

```
async def get_api_response(photo_bytes, api_key, language):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(URL_API,
                                data={
                                    "picture.png": photo_bytes,
                                    "apikey": api_key,
                                    "language": language
                                }) as response:
            return await response.text()
```

И вот цикл перебора апи ключей (находится в хендлере aiogram, но это ничего не решает):

```
for api_key in API_KEYS:
    response = json.loads(await get_api_response(photo_bytes=photo_bytes, api_key=api_key, language=photo_lang))
    print(response)
```

Когда пробую вставить цикл в функцию с запросом, то возникает такая же ошибка. Но когда вызываю функцию без цикла, то ошибки нету. Какие есть предложения, как исправить ошибку с минимальными изминениями?

Логика такая кода такая: если при переборе API ключей в цикле API ключ работает, то брейкаем(break) цикл.

**UPD: В ХОДЕ МНОГОЧАСОВЫХ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ Я ПОНЯЛ, ЧТО ОШИБКА ВЫЛАЗИТ, ПОТОМУ ЧТО ПОСЛЕ ПЕРВОГО ЦИКЛА ЗАКРЫВАЕТСЯ PHOTO_BYTES**

Вот сама инициализация photo_bytes:

```
photo = cv2.imread(photo_path)
unused_var, compressed_image = cv2.imencode('.png', photo, [1, 90])
photo_bytes = io.BytesIO(compressed_image)
```

Comment: Чекни, обновил вопрос, нашёл суть ошибки.

Comment: photo_bytes — это просто дескриптор байтового потока, а не байтоавые данные.https://pythononline.ru/osnovy/modul-io-python

Comment: Сергей Шашко, это понятно, что сжатое изображение находится в памяти, но какое будет оптимальное решение для этого? К примеру: сохранять сжатое изображение в папку, а потом считывать и передавать байты этого же изображения в функцию? Или может в каждом цикле инициализировать сжатое изображение? Будем, крч, пробовать)

Comment: "сохранять сжатое изображение в папку'  я думаю что это лишнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну типа что-то такого

```
with io.BytesIO(compressed_image) as f:
    photo_bytes = f.read()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!